# Groovy method declaration in JMeter JSR223 Assertion

Tags: testing, groovy, jmeter

I am trying to declare Groovy method in JMeter version 4.0 JSR223 Assertion like this:

```
public void mandatorySizeVerification(Object element, int id, String childName, int size, String failureMessage) {
     def child = elemet.get(childName);
        if(child == null || child.length() <= 0){       
            failureMessage += "element id: " + id.toString() + " has no " + childName + "!\n";      
        }else{
            if(child.length() > size){
                failureMessage += childName + ":" + child.toString() + " is mandatory and it must be less than "
                                    + size + " chars.\n";
            }
        }
}
```

But when I call the method I got this error:

```
Assertion failure message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: elemet for class: Script124
```

Comment: You have a typo here `def child = elemet.get(childName);` It should be `element`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but error still appears.

Comment: There was a typo in object that has been passed too everything works now ! Thanks. :D

Comment: Consider removing this question -typos in code don't provide any value to other people.

Comment: You are right I will reedit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, there were 2 problems:

- typo when using element, you used elemet
- wrong object passed as parameter